# Encontrar el índice del elemento con mayor valor en un arreglo

Tags: java, array

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
"Escribir un método static int maximoIndice(int[] a) que dado un arreglo de enteros no vacío, devuelve el índice del valor más alto que aparece."
Ésta es la parte del código que creo que está mal o que hay algo que falta.

```
    public static int maximoIndice(int[] a, int cant)
    {
        int maximoIndice=0;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<cant; i++)
        {
            if(i>maximoIndice)
            {
                System.out.print("El valor maximo se encuentra en la posicion "+i);
            }
        }
        return(i); 
    }
```

El problema aparece cuando corro el programa; esto es lo que sucede:
Luego de escribir todos los valores que van dentro del array, cuando debería aparecer el índice con el valor máximo, esta línea aparece escrita dos veces, pero con números distintos.

Comment: Pon en el título el problema específico en cuestión, y la salida _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Piénsalo, si alguien llega a tener un problema similar al tuyo, ¿cómo encontrarán tu pregunta si se titula así?

Comment: Gracias por efectivamente mejorar tu pregunta, ¡bienvenida/o a [es.so]!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para hallar el indice con el valor mas alto,primero debes hallar el valor mas alto,no es recomendable tener un print dentro de un bucle xk este puede repetirse varias veces

```
public static int maximoIndice(int[] a, int cant)
    {
        int numeroMax=0;
        int maximoIndice=0;

        
        for (int i=0; i<cant; i++)
        {
//si algun valor dentro del array es mayor al numeroMax
            if(a[i]>numeroMax) 
            {
//numeroMax sera igual a ese valor en el array
              numeroMax=a[i];
//y por ende el maximo indice sera el indice de ese numeroMax
              maximoIndice=i; 
            }
        }
        return(maximoIndice); 
    }
```

ahora en el main imprimes el resultado

```
System.out.println("el numero maximo se encuentra en el indice "+maximoIndice(a,cant));
```

Answer (score 0):

Según el código que nos muestras, el detalle está en que el índice del arreglo está comenzando desde 0, deberías sumar 1 al resultado de la posición para que sea tal cual la posición del número que ingreses:

```
public static int maximoIndice(int[] a, int cant)
    {
        int maximoIndice=0;
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<cant; i++)
        {
            if(i>maximoIndice)
            {
                System.out.print("El valor maximo se encuentra en la posicion "+ (i+1));
            }
        }
        return(i); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te presento esta otra opción que haciendo uso de Streams consigue el resultado esperado y coincide con la firma del método que nos describes:

> static int maximoIndice(int[] a)

```
/**
 * Dado un arreglo de enteros no vacío, devuelve el índice del valor más alto que aparece.
 * @param arreglo Arreglo de enteros no vacío de cuyo elemento con valor mas alto se obtendra el indice.
 * @return Indice del elemento del mayor valor del arrelgo recibido como argumento.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException Cuando el arreglo de enteros esta vacío.
 */
public static int maximoIndice(int[] arreglo) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    
    // Arreglo no vacio
    if(arreglo.length < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El arreglo debe contener elementos");
    }
    
    // Generamos lista con los elementos del stream.
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arreglo).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Obtenemos el mayor numero.
    Integer maxValue = Arrays.stream(arreglo).max().getAsInt();
    
    // Obtenemos su indice.
    return list.indexOf(maxValue);
}
```